# Como cambiar la fecha y hora del sistema desde android studio

Tags: android-studio

Necesito modificar la fecha y hora del sistema mediante una aplicación en Android studio.

Comment: Hola jesus, esta es una pregunta más del tipo búsqueda en google y no entra dentro del formato de este sitio, por lo que eventualmente terminará cerrada, te recomiendo que revise [ask]. Saludos.

Comment: Que has intentado Jesus? tienes algo?